# firebase to bigquery -> counting occurances of nested custom event with specific values

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm having problems counting custom event occurrences by the event value (it has multiple).

I'm currently trying to make this work:

```
SELECT  count(*) as count,app_info.id,event_date,event_name,platform,events.value.string_value
    FROM `api-6xxx.analytics_xxx.events_*`
    CROSS JOIN UNNEST(event_params) as events
    WHERE _table_suffix BETWEEN '20200225' AND '20200229'
    AND event_name = 'ad_finished'
    AND app_info.id = 'com.bundle.app'
    AND platform = "ANDROID"
    AND events.key = 'ad_type'
    AND traffic_source.source = 'google'
    AND events.value.string_value <> 'specific_thing'
    GROUP BY 2,3,4,5,6
    ORDER BY event_date
```

The problem is that it does not filter by the **AND events.value.string_value <> 'specific_thing'**, and I have no idea why.

Comment: Could you provide an example of your data and confirm the structure of the field events.value.string_value? Also, the schema would be helpful

Comment: If you are using ARRAY, consider that for this type, comparisions are not supported https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#data_types

Comment: It's a "repeated record" used by bigquery by default if the event has multiple nested values as a struct

Comment: Could you change this as:
SELECT  count(*) as count,app_info.id,event_date,event_name,platform,events.value.string_value
    FROM `api-6xxx.analytics_xxx.events_*`
    CROSS JOIN UNNEST(event_params.value) as events
    WHERE _table_suffix BETWEEN '20200225' AND '20200229'
    AND event_name = 'ad_finished'
    AND app_info.id = 'com.bundle.app'
    AND platform = "ANDROID"
    AND events.key = 'ad_type'
    AND traffic_source.source = 'google'
    AND events.string_value <> 'specific_thing'
    GROUP BY 2,3,4,5,6
    ORDER BY event_date

Comment: I get an error on the unnest - Cannot access field value on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value STRUCT<string_value STRING, int_value INT64, float_value FLOAT64, ...>>>

Comment: it would be helpful if you can share some data in an AVRO or JSON file to replicate your issue.